# Comments, questions and answers in same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add questions and answers to a comment with the forms all on the comment show page.  Adding a question works but adding an answer redirects to '/questions//answers' with the error

```
No route matches [POST] "/questions/answers"
```

Here are my routes:

```
resources :comments do
  resources :questions do
 end
end 

resources :questions do
  resources :answers do
 end
end
```

Here is the comments show view:

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<%= @comment.question %>
<%= render :partial => "answers/form" %>
<% end %>
```

The answers form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@question, Answer.new] do |f| %>
<%= f.input :body %>
<% end %>
```

and the comments controller:

```
def show
@comment = Comment.find params[:id]
@questions = @comment.questions
@answer = Answer.new      
end
```

and finally the answers controller:

```
def create
@question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
@answer = @question.answers.new(answer_params)
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your answer form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@question, Answer.new] do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :body %>   
<% end %>
```

from where u getting @question

may be following changes will fix your problem try it

Here is the comments show view:

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= @comment.question %>
    <%= render :partial => "answers/form", locals: {question:question} %>
<% end %>
```

The answers form:

```
<%= simple_form_for [question, Answer.new] do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :body %>   
<% end %>
```

and your answers controller

```
def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = @question.answers.new(answer_params)
    @answer.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're more likely to find something like this to work:

```
questions/1/answers
```

Just guessing. You can inspect the output of `rake routes` and i would imagine that you will see something like this:

```
questions/:id/answers
```

Answer (score 0):

In the create method you are never saving to the database.  `@answer` will never have an id.

AnswersController#create

```
@answer = @question.answers.create(answer_params)
```

not

```
@answer = @question.answers.new(answer_params)
```

I don't see in the code you are sharing where the problem would error but even if it is not the fix... it will be a problem.